# как String в котором записан два параметра с плавающей точкой преобразовать в List<double>?

Tags: flutter, dart

например есть такая строка:

```
String str = "45.2, 50.2";
```

его нужно преобразовать в List;

должно получиться:

```
List<double> dbl = [45.2, 50.2];
```

Comment: Эммм а чо за ЯП?

Comment: flutter - sdk от гугл, построенное на языке dart

Comment: зачем кодить на языке который никому не нужен?...

Comment: @Данил вам может и ненужен, но как быть другим людям? _У Flutter достаточно быстро растущие комюнити (в геометрической прогрессии)._

Comment: Мне кажется и через лет 20 Flutter не попадет и в топ 30

Comment: @Данил как я вижу: некоторые мои знакомые перешли с RN, Kotlin, Swift и Frontend в Flutter. Они говорят что им нравиться Flutter, некоторые из них уже работают с этой технологией и в ближайшие время не собираются менять стек. Также посмотрите на тренды технологий за [12 мес.](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=React%20Native,%2Fg%2F11f03_rzbg) и [5 лет](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=today%205-y&q=React%20Native,%2Fg%2F11f03_rzbg)

Comment: а что на нем пишут?

Comment: @Данил вообще разрабатывается как мультиплатформенное решение, то-есть где есть экран и возможность для взаимодействия оно будет работать. Пока работает на Android и iOS. Web в бете, а Win, Linux, MacOS в альфе + FuchsiaOS. Собирается в нативку (AOT, без какой либо прослойки), для разработки используют JIT(для Hot Reload и других плюшек).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решил сам, оставлю ответ здесь может кому то пригодится:

```
String str = "50.2, 23.45";
String convert = '[$str]';
var ab = json.decode(convert);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ещё можно сделать так (а ещё можно было использовать RegEx):

```
void main() {
  String str = "45.2, 50.2";
  List<double> dbl = str.split(",").map((v) => double.parse(v)).toList();
  print(dbl);
}
```